# Cartesian Product; The Topology of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: general-topology, cross-product

Let $S^{1}=\left \{(x, y) : x^{2}+y^{2}=1 \right \}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be the unit circle. What familiar shape is $S^{1}×S^{1}$?

Comment: It's the torus.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the title. How is $S^1 \times S^1$ related to $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: It is isomorphic to a  doughnut. ${}{}{}$

Comment: I really dislike when people immediately realize the torus in $\mathbb R^3$ as a definition. It is not totally obvious from what a Cartesian product is that this thing embeds into $\mathbb R^3$. It helps to think of this thing first as a surface in $\mathbb R^4$, and then show that it has this embedding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can learn more about your question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus

[image: This is from Wikipedia]